# Parametrized Inductive Types in Agda

Tags: gadt, agda

I'm just reading [*Dependent Types at Work*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/DependentTypesAtWork.pdf). In the introduction to parametrised types, the author mentions that in this declaration

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
  []   : List A
  _::_ : A → List A → List A
```

the type of `List` is `Set → Set` and that `A` becomes implicit argument to both constructors, ie.

```
[]   : {A : Set} → List A
_::_ : {A : Set} → A → List A → List A
```

Well, I tried to rewrite it a bit differently

```
data List : Set → Set where
  []   : {A : Set} → List A
  _::_ : {A : Set} → A → List A → List A
```

which sadly doesn't work (I'm trying to learn Agda for two days or so, but from what I gathered it's because the constructors are parametrised over `Set₀` and so `List A` must be in `Set₁`).

Indeed, the following is accepted

```
data List : Set₀ → Set₁ where
  []   : {A : Set₀} → List A
  _::_ : {A : Set₀} → A → List A → List A
```

however, I'm no longer able to use `{A : Set} → ... → List (List A)` (which is perfectly understandable).

So my question: What is the actual difference between `List (A : Set) : Set` and `List : Set → Set`?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I take the liberty to rename the data types. The first, which is
indexed on `Set` will be called `ListI`, and the second `ListP`,
has `Set` as a parameter:

```
data ListI : Set → Set₁ where
  []  : {A : Set} → ListI A
  _∷_ : {A : Set} → A → ListI A → ListI A

data ListP (A : Set) : Set where
  []  : ListP A
  _∷_ : A → ListP A → ListP A
```

In data types parameters go before the colon, and arguments after the
colon are called indicies. The constructors can be used in the same
way, you can apply the implicit set:

```
nilI : {A : Set} → ListI A
nilI {A} = [] {A}

nilP : {A : Set} → ListP A
nilP {A} = [] {A}
```

There difference comes when pattern matching. For the indexed version we have:

```
null : {A : Set} → ListI A → Bool
null ([]  {A})     = true
null (_∷_ {A} _ _) = false
```

This cannot be done for `ListP`:

```
-- does not work
null′ : {A : Set} → ListP A → Bool
null′ ([]  {A})     = true
null′ (_∷_ {A} _ _) = false
```

The error message is

```
The constructor [] expects 0 arguments, but has been given 1
when checking that the pattern [] {A} has type ListP A
```

`ListP` can also be defined with a dummy module, as `ListD`:

```
module Dummy (A : Set) where
  data ListD : Set where
    []  : ListD
    _∷_ : A → ListD → ListD

open Dummy public
```

Perhaps a bit surprising, `ListD` is equal to `ListP`. We cannot pattern
match on the argument to `Dummy`:

```
-- does not work
null″ : {A : Set} → ListD A → Bool
null″ ([]  {A})     = true
null″ (_∷_ {A} _ _) = false
```

This gives the same error message as for `ListP`.

`ListP` is an example of a parameterised data type, which is simpler
than `ListI`, which is an inductive family: it "depends" on the
indicies, although in this example in a trivial way.

Parameterised data types are defined on [the
wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.ParameterizedInductiveTypes),
and
[here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/darcs/Agda2/examples/Introduction/Data/Parameterised.agda)
is a small introduction.

Inductive families are not really defined, but elaborated on in [the
wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Main.InductiveFamilies)
with the canonical example of something that seems to need inductive
families:

```
data Term (Γ : Ctx) : Type → Set where
  var : Var Γ τ → Term Γ τ
  app : Term Γ (σ → τ) → Term Γ σ → Term Γ τ
  lam : Term (Γ , σ) τ → Term Γ (σ → τ)
```

Disregarding the Type index, a simplified version of this could not be
written with in the `Dummy`-module way because of `lam` constructor.

Another good reference is [Inductive
Families](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.74)
by Peter Dybjer from 1997.

Happy Agda coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's still one thing I'd like to know (my question might have been a bit ambiguous, I'm afraid): I cannot define `List` as `Set → Set` to prevent inconsistency in the type system, what is the actual mechanism that makes `List (A : Set) : Set` "work"? Because to me (coming from Haskell background), they both seem to be `data List :: * -> * where (...)`, but one works and the other doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have already stated the reason; to avoid inconsistencies constructors with Set as an argument must necessary belong in Set₁. The parametric data types allows us to write datatypes that with indicies would have to end up one level "higher", and it "works" just because of the well-behaved conditions of parametric datatypes. On the other hand, there is some controversy how "safe" the inductive families are, as the page to the wiki illustrates, and I think the current consensus is to have some small and trusted Agda code that fancy data types can be translated to.

Comment: Dybjer's distinction between "parameter" and "index" is the thing that you bring out with your `Dummy` module. In his terminology, Term's Gamma argument is most definitely an index. The assertion that "parameters go before the colon, and arguments after the colon are called indices" is misleading (in that it does not characterize the distinction) and arguably false. It is possible (but unwise) to put parameters after the colon. It is possible (and common, and wise) to put indices left of the colon. The key point is that indices may vary node-to-node, but parameters are fixed for a whole value.