# Agda – difference between type args on the left and right side of the colon

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-level-computation, curry-howard

Following definition compiles and behaves well:

```
data Eq {lvl} {A : Set lvl} (x : A) : A → Set where
  refl : Eq x x
```

However this one does not compile:

```
data Eq {lvl} {A : Set lvl} (x : A) (y : A) : Set where
  refl : Eq x x
```

because

```
x != y of type A
when checking the constructor refl in the declaration of Eq
```

I don't understand why they aren't equivalent. What's the difference and why the second variant is not correct?

Comment: I was surprised to see that this rather fundamental question apparently hasn't been asked yet (though see the related question linked in my answer). So, thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments on the left of the colon are called parameters; those on the right are called indices. The difference between the two is this: In the return type of the data type's constructors, the parameters must always be exactly the variables from the type declaration. The indices, on the other hand, can be arbitrary terms (of the correct type).

In your second example, the return type of `refl` is `Eq x x`. However, `y` is a parameter, so the return type would have to be `Eq x y`. In your first example, the type of `refl` is legal because `y` is an index and `x` is a term of type `A`.

By 'return type' I mean the expression to the right of the last arrow in a constructor's type. To illustrate, here is the definition of length-indexed lists aka vectors:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc : ℕ → ℕ

data Vec (A : Set) : ℕ → Set where
  [] : Vec A zero
  _∷_ : ∀ {n} → A → Vec A n → Vec A (suc n)
```

The return type of `_∷_` is `Vec A (suc n)`. Again, `suc n` is an arbitrary expression of type `ℕ`. If the data type occurs in the type of an argument of a constructor, as with the `Vec A n` argument to `_∷_`, both the parameters and the indexes can be arbitrary terms (though we use the same parameter here).

When you pattern match on an indexed data type, the constructor's index can give you additional information. Consider `head` on vectors:

```
head : ∀ {A n} → Vec A (suc n) → A
head (x ∷ xs) = x
```

We don't need to write an equation for the constructor `[]` because its type is `Vec A zero` whereas the type of the pattern is `Vec A (suc n)` and these types cannot be equal. Similarly, consider the following proof that your equality is symmetric:

```
data Eq {l} {A : Set l} (x : A) : A → Set where
  refl : Eq x x

sym : {A : Set} (x y : A) → Eq x y → Eq y x
sym x .x refl = refl
```

By pattern matching on `refl`, we learn that `y` is, in fact, `x`. This is indicated by the dot pattern `.x`. Thus, our goal becomes `x ≡ x`, which can be proven with `refl` again. More formally, `x` is [unified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) with `y` when we match on `refl`.

You might wonder whether you should simply declare all arguments of a data type as indices. I believe that in Agda, there's no downside to doing so, but it's good style to declare arguments as parameters if possible (since these are simpler).

Related: [section of the Agda manual](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/data-types.html#parametrized-datatypes); 
[SO question with more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962873/parametrized-inductive-types-in-agda?rq=1).

Comment: This answer is fine as far as it goes, but it reflects a recent and common, but in my view unhelpful, shift away from Dybjer's distinction between "parameters" and "indices" in inductive families. A true parameter is used uniformly not only in constructor return types but in all recursive uses of the datatype, so that it could be abstracted as a module parameter. There are *two* kinds of indices: sadly there is no agreed terminology to distinguish them, so here goes. Right of colon are "return-specific" indices. Left of colon we can have "return-generic" indices which vary in recursive uses.

Comment: @pigworker, "so that it could be abstracted as a module parameter" -- we could abstract a "varying" parameter, if we had a way to refer to the current module. Like `module M n where data Term where Lam : M.Term (suc n) -> Term`. It'd nice to define functions like `map : forall B -> (A -> B) -> List -> M.List B` this way (for `List` defined in a module `M` parameterized by `A`). Might be a feature request...

Comment: Were that to happen, they would no longer be module "parameters".